data is not being received
I'm writing a code which transfer data between server and client using socket. I'm transferring both strings and objects of classes I made. some of the messages Im sendings are larger than 1024 bytes and therefore I’m dividing it to chunks.
send:
 for message in messages:
    client,msg=message
    print(msg)
    data = pickle.dumps(msg)
    print(data)
    if client in wlist:
        # Calculate the number of chunks needed
        num_chunks = (len(data) + 1023) // 1024
        # Send the number of chunks first
        pickle_num=pickle.dumps(num_chunks)
        print(pickle_num)
        client.send(pickle_num)
        # Send data in chunks of 1024 bytes
        for i in range(num_chunks):
            start_index = i * 1024
            end_index = min((i + 1) * 1024, len(data))
            chunk = data[start_index:end_index]
            client.send(chunk)
        print(num_chunks)
        messages.remove(message)

recieve:
def client_socket(client,msg_send,locker,msg_recieve):
    def receive_data(client, message):
        # Receive the number of chunks
        num_chunks = pickle.loads(message)
        # Receive data chunks
        received_data = ""
        for _ in range(num_chunks):
            chunk = client.recv(1024)
            received_data += chunk
        print(received_data)
        data = pickle.loads(received_data)
        print(data)
        # Unpickle the received data
        return data
    while True:
        locker.acquire()
        for i in msg_send:
            msg=pickle.dumps(i)
            client.send(msg)
            msg_send.remove(i)
        locker.release()
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([client] ,[client], [], 0.5)
        for client in rlist:
            try:
                message=client.recv(1024)
            except:
                #תקלת תקשורת
                messagebox.showerror('error', ' communication failed')
            else:
                if message != "":
                    msg = receive_data(client, message)
                    locker.acquire()
                    msg_recieve.append(msg)
                    locker.release()

I tried to create method that find how many chunks of 1024 bytes are required and sending it so the other user expect them. however it seems like the the user do not get the num of the chunks.
I would appreciate your help

When using a stream protocol like TCP, the chunks you get from .recv() have no relationship whatsoever to the chunks that were transmitted with .send() - the only guarantee is that you get all of the bytes, in their original order.  You need to send the total length of the pickled data (as a fixed-length string, most likely), and then call .recv() in a loop until you get that much data.

Since you get bytes in order sent, no need to send in chunks either. Just .sendall() the whole data.

@jasonharper thanks, do you have any idea how when we send the data length and the data itself we can separate them from each other?

That's why using a fixed-length string for the length is a good idea - you call .recv() in a loop until you receive that length of data, parse the number contained in it, then call .recv() in a loop until you receive that length of data.  You can alternate between the two loops as many times as you want during a single connection.
